# How to have jQuery UI Slider widget autoplay a text timeline of years?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I'm not sure how to creat a jQuery slider that can show in it's ***slider-track*** a **Yearly Timeline** and have it **auto-play** with the current year ***shown in the handle*** as well?

Popular Website Example:  **http://maps.eyesontheforest.or.id/**

In the left side panel there is a **"Natural Forest Cover"** section which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's a screenshot of the JavaScript timeline shown in blue.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MFNkD/)

The reference URL in your webpage is using a framework other than JavaScript for that animation which includes a playback feature. **EDIT:** It's using [**Google Maps API Visualization Library**](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization)

However my jsFiddle above is done using **jQuery** and **jQuery UI** since a **Slider plugin** with it's own CSS is used.

[image]

When using `years` for the purple text, you'll soon discover those are just mere labels that don't necessarily reflect the actual position value... *just the position location*.

[**jsFiddle DEMO YEARS with Autoplay Timeline Button *setTimeout* Method**](http://jsfiddle.net/GpULk/)

[**jsFiddle DEMO YEARS with Autoplay Timeline Button *setInterval* Method**](http://jsfiddle.net/GpULk/1/)

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ...which framework is that which is being used in the reference website ...... i was not find any reference in the script section

Comment: Using Google Chrome Developer Tools, I did an **Break on Attribute Change** on the dragable handle bar on the timeline. It turns out that it's using **Google Maps API** to achieve that functionality, which is on line 160 of that HTML page. See Edit in answer for that library.

Comment: can we make it auto slide i tried out some options but it did not work

Comment: The markup I've included makes it auto slide. For example, you can click inside of the slider bar, click the Purple or Green year and it will slide the `handle` to that location automatically. Normally the slider widget doesn't do that. ***However, I know you mean Autoplay which is what the original website does.*** You were right, it was tricky in getting it to work correctly. I found out that you need to call `.slider()` with only the `value` to have it ***visually slide***. Updated in my Answer is a revised DEMO YEARS jsFiddle that now includes **Autoplay Timeline Button**. Cheers!